# QGIS Hillshade from a specific "light" source in space, not azimuth/altitude of light

Tags: qgis, hillshade

I am trying to determine locations on a map that will have a clear line of sight to a satellite in geostationary orbit. Given a terrain raster I'd like to determine what areas of the map are in the "shade" and which could see the satellite. The problem is in QGIS you have to give an azimuth and altitude of light source, but obviously that will change depending where you are on the map?

Has anyone tried using hill shade that doesn't use a fixed light source, or the sun with a date/time?

Comment: I may be a viewshed you're looking for rather than a hillshade. For this you would add the satellite's position as an observer point. Would it be possible to work out the coordinates that the satellite would be at if it was on the surface of the earth and then give it an elevation equal to its distance from Earth?